# How to rewrite URL in htaccess for specific folders in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would need assistance in rewriting URLS. Here are the given

```
Site URL: http://example.com:8000/myapp
```

Current htaccess

```
Allow from localhost

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

my site is in

```
/var/www/htdocs/myapp
```

virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs"
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/custom/a_local_error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/custom/a_local_access_log" common
    <Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is that my assets are located in the same folder as the app but the code for including the assets are in absolute. Example:

```
/_js/jquery.js
/_js/myjs.js
```

Is it possible to rewrite it to:

```
/_js/myqpp/jquery.js
/_js/myapp/myjs.js
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want /var/www/htdocs/_js/myapp/jquery.js to point to /var/www/htdocs/_js/jquery.js? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^(_js)/([^/.]+\.js)$ /$1/myapp/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Why "hehe"??? Did you submit enough information in your comment? What URL did you try? Where did you place this rule in your htaccess?

Comment: I placed it below the "Rewrite Engine on" as you instructed. The URL i tried was:
`http://example.com:8000/myapp`

Comment: Read your question again. Problem we are solving is to redirect `/_js/jquery.js` to `/_js/myapp/jquery.js`. You need to use this URL: `http://example.com:8000/_js/jquery.js` and see if gets redirected or not.

Comment: Yes i tried that too. But it did not redirect to the desired URL

Comment: I can only help if you read my comments carefully and answer all the questions I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the following should work for this:

```
RewriteRule ^/_js/jquery.js$ /_js/myapp/jquery.js [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/_js/myjs.js$ /_js/myapp/myjs.js [NC,L]
```

And try that before your other rewrite rule.